# Google Eclipse plugin recompile problem

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have installed Eclipse Helios(3.6) and Google plugin to develope app in GAE/J.Then created project and runned it sucessufull. Later made some changes in source code but it doesnt recompiled. Previous compiled version is in use. It doesnt compile until I make changes in appengine-web.xml. Could you suggest how to solve the problem please?

**PS** : I had the same problem in Eclipse 3.5. Also I added javac to SYSTEMPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

- the folder where your java files are in is a "source folder" (check it via project properties, "build path")
- turn on "build automatically"? Can be found in Menu "Project"
- Maybe refreshing your workspace automatically will help (Window->Preferences, and search for workspace)

Answer (score 0):

The Project is automatically not builded or recompiled, when there are problems marked by eclipse. Take a look into the marker panel of eclipse and solve the problems.